# Beautiful Soup webscraper stops after 1st "Scrape"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a scraper.

When I run the code, the for loop is only running once. It just stops after running 1 time and it gives out the same result twice.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://opensea.io/collection/morethangamersnftmtg?search[toggles][0]=BUY_NOW"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

request= Request(url, headers=headers)
page_html = urlopen(request).read()


html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

nft_items = html_soup.find_all("div" , class_="Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 dBFmez AssetsSearchView--assets")

filename = "MTG.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "title, price \n"

f.write(headers)

for nft in nft_items:
    title = nft.find("div" , class_="Overflowreact__OverflowContainer-sc-10mm0lu-0 kohuDY").text
    price = nft.find("div" , class_="Overflowreact__OverflowContainer-sc-10mm0lu-0 gjwKJf Price--amount").text

    f.write(title + "," + price)
    
    #f.close()
```

Comment: It is very likely that the page is dynamic. You might want to consider using selenium with firefox or chrome driver to navigate the UI.

Comment: Also what is the HTML page content? Without it, this question can't be analysed meaningfully.

Comment: How can it emit the same result twice when the loop only runs once?